# Set a cookie in JS on the script domain

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a page on `domainA.com`

which calls a script `<script src="https://domainB.com/script.js"></script>`

can I set from `script.js` in javascript a cookie on domainB? 
Or I can only do it server-side with http header?

I tried with `document.cookie = '..; domain=domainB.com;...';` but it nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript always executes in the context of the HTML document it is running inside.

> can I set from script.js in javascript a cookie on domainB?

Not with client-side JS.

> Or I can only do it server-side with http header?

Yes. This could be set in the HTTP response to the request for `script.js`.